# Moonrise and moonset roughly at the same hour for few days

Tags: the-moon

I generated ephemeris for my town (15.10, 17.03) and what caught my attention is for some days in a row, the difference between moonrise is like 15 minutes (diffence between moonset is ~1h at a time):[image]

However a couple days later situation is mirrored for moonset, namely difference between moonset in like ~25min and difference between moonrise is more than hour.

Could someone explain this to me? Thank you!

Link to [ephemeris](https://in-the-sky.org/ephemeris.php?ird=1&irs=1&ima=1&iob=1&objtype=1&objpl=Moon&objtxt=the%20Moon&tz=0&startday=6&startmonth=6&startyear=2023&interval=4&rows=250).

Comment: Also see https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/48591/the-moon-rises-at-a-different-time-each-day-but-that-difference-changes-why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Moon’s orbit is slightly tilted (about 5.15°) with respect to the *ecliptic*, and the direction of this tilt is variable over a period of about 18.61 years. This means its tilt with respect to the *equator* is variable. But even if it weren’t, when the Moon is near the node (the crossing of its orbit with the equator), its “vertical” movement becomes faster, and it’s slower around 90° from the nodes. This explains why sometimes there is more or less time between two successive moonrises or moonsets, as the declination of the Moon “compensates” for its difference in right ascension which would make its risings and settings (almost) regularly spaced from each other.