How many times does the moon rise between two new moons?
How many times does the moon rise between two new moons?
This might be a silly question not meeting the standards here, in that case I will delete it.
I have tried to write a program using perl, but it looks like there is no module that gives the time of moon rise, and beside, it would not improve understanding. Searching the net, I find the time for moon rise for a town called Perl, but nothing that improves my understanding.

It's not a silly question, but there's not a simple general answer. Near the north or south pole, the Moon can be above the horizon for ~2 weeks.  https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/57591/16685 At any location the time between moonrises varies quite a bit  https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/48594/16685 The motion of the Moon is complicated! https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/55112/16685

Just for amusement: I have seen the full moon setting in the east. You don't believe me? I was on the western side of a valley with north-south direction. It was getting dark, and I went downhill quickly to get home before actual nightfall. So, just by geometry, the moon vanished behind the hill on the opposite side of the valley.

For a rough estimate (for non-polar regions), a mean synodic month is ~29.53 days. But the Moon "laps" the Sun (relative to the stars) from one New Moon to the next, so there are ~28.53 moonrises per synodic month.

For "normal" attitudes, there is usually one day per lunation when the moon does not set until the next day, similarly usually one day it doesn't rise.  And the number of days per lunation isn't fixed, so best anyone can give is an average like PM 2Ring did above.

@PM_2Ring: Your simple answer is vorrect. Put it in an answer box for fame and fortune.
